# Replace glassfish javax.servlet.jsp in jetty

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets, jetty

The default jsp dependencies changed from glasfish to apache in jetty version 9.2.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jsp.html

I have tried to replace all jsp dependencies in a project to apache but I have not succeeded to replace javax.servlet.jsp to a working apache dependency:

```
groupId: org.glassfish.web                                        
artifactId: javax.servlet.jsp 
version: 2.3.2
```

So are there any alternative dependency which I should use instead or is org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet still the best dependency to use when packaging a runnable war?

The exception thrown when removing the javax.servlet.jsp dependency is:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the api libraries on the build time classpath. These should be marked with scope 'provided' which indicates that they should not be bundled in any generated artifact (WAR) as they will be provided by the Servlet container at runtime.

Thus in your pom you should have the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the absence of any other container specific behaviour, the above change makes your application portable across all containers compliant with the relevant version of the Servlet specification.